# PDA with N-Stacks comparison with Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, pushdown-automata

Is it possible to compare PDA having N-Stacks with Turning Machines. Are they equally powerful in this situation?

It's been told that PDA with 2-Stacks is equally powerful to Turning Machine. But what if we add more stacks i.e. 3, 4, 5...N to PDA; will it become more powerful or it can serve same purpose.

Comment: The same question was posted earlier today, and marked as a duplicate.

Comment: What about more than 2-stacks addition to PDA. I'm unable to find this information on the forum

Comment: The linked question answers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 stacks is enough for a PDA to be as powerful as a Turing Machine. Basically, you can pop from one stack and push into the other to simulate moving across the tape head, writing, etc.

In fact, a 2-counter machine is as powerful as a Turing Machine, though the proof is much more involved. There's a sketch of it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Two-counter_machines_are_Turing_equivalent_.28with_a_caveat.29)

Comment: What if we add more stacks (3,4,5,...N) to PDA

Comment: For computability? Nothing. We know of no models more powerful than Turing Machines.